# Alternative to iframe for microservices ui composition

Tags: iframe, microservices

I'm currently integrating multiple microservices ui into a web portal. I have a navigation sidebar with link to microservices which will be loaded into an iframe in the central area.

I have lot of issue with iframe (security with frame option header, window sizing, etc...)

Do you know about a better alternative to an iframe?

Comment: http://particular.net/blog/secret-of-better-ui-composition

Comment: https://dejanglozic.com/2014/10/20/micro-services-and-page-composition-problem/

Answer (score 1):

If your micro services have a REST API available, you can use an embeded javascript code instead of iframe. Your embed code would look something like:

```html
<div id="embed_id"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  
(function(){
  var embededJavascriptElement = document.createElement("script"); 
  embededJavascriptElement.type = "text/javascript";
  embededJavascriptElement.charset= "utf-8";
  embededJavascriptElement.id = "embed_script";
  embededJavascriptElement.src = "<path to your script>";
  (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.getElementsByTagName("body")  [0]).appendChild(embededJavascriptElement);
 })();
</script>
```

The script above will insert another script tag into your DOM. That script will be interpreted, will search for the element with id ="embed_id" and will render the embeded code into that div (you need to implement this behavior).

Answer (score 1):

You already tagged your question accordingly with spring-cloud and Zuul. I'd suggest this is exactly the way to go cause this way you can avoid the browsers sandbox as well as to manage CORS headers on your services. Just use [start.spring.io](http://start.spring.io) and include Zuul as a requirement and define your rules. I suggest you start with static routes and if you then are familiar and confident with Zuul, embed a service registry and discovery like Eureka, consul or etcd.

Comment: You'r right @daniel for spring-cloud and zuul, they solve sandbox and CORS issues. What about alternative to iframe for ui composition (with eader, sidebar, footer) for multiple microservices, do you know about any?

Comment: To me its now not quite clear what you are trying to achieve. Do you have some sort of a widget library that you want to flexibly display? Something like iGoogle had? Or are you just trying to combine input from various smaller services into one page? I mean is your desire to combine on the client side or server side? On client side I'd suggest you look into angular. And for serverside just get a service with e.g. Thymeleaf as engine to retrieve all of the content and send back a fully rendered html page.

Comment: in short i want multiples ui microservices to share some common parts: header, navigation menu, footer, etc...